# Onclick on a div not firing up in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The problem is that I have a onclick on a div which is not firing up.

```
            <div className={styles.scrollingDiv}>
                <div className={styles.rectangleDiv} />
                <div className={styles.menuBarDiv}>
                    <div className={styles.rectangleDiv16} />
                    <div className={styles.rectangleDiv17} />
                    <div className={styles.rectangleDiv18} />
                    <div className={styles.rectangleDiv19} />
                    <div className={styles.rectangleDiv20} />
                    <div className={styles.ostrichRacewayDiv} onClick={ostrichRacewayClick}>Ostrich Raceway</div>
                    <div className={styles.nVOIBlogDiv} onClick={blogClick}>NVOI Blog</div>
                    <div className={styles.homeDiv} onClick={function() { alert("hello world"); }}>Home</div>
                    <img className={styles.starIcon} alt="" src="star-1.svg" />
                    <div className={styles.newDiv}>New</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.noScrollingDiv} />
            <div className={styles.noScrollingDiv} />
        </div>
```

I am expecting when the div is clicked, it should navigate. However, that is not happening! Why is that?

Comment: There's probably no need to wrap all those handlers in `useCallback`.

Comment: @Andy I have tried without the call back and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @ShubhamNanda Can you please brief which on click method isn't working ?

Comment: @aman-sadhwani hey all the three onclicks mentioned in the code are not working. I tried something like this <div className={styles.homeDiv} onClick={alert("hello world"); } but it resulted in alert on render and then no click event fired up on subsequent clicks on the div.

Comment: Looks like overlapping div was causing the issue. Resolved, removing noScrollingDiv helped resolving the click issue.

Comment: have you tried ```<div className={styles.ostrichRacewayDiv} onClick={()=>ostrichRacewayClick()}>Ostrich Raceway</div>```?

Answer (score -2):

Onclicks work like this, try this instead :

```
<button onclick="alert('Hello World')">Click me</button>
```

Comment: That's HTML. The question is asking about JSX in React.